# Bots Engine Names for search spiders

Tags: search, web-crawler

- googlebot
- msnbot
- yahoo
- bingbot
- googlebot-image

This is all the big search engine spiders? or someone know more famous spiders?

and does the names of the spiders I wrote there current?

thx!

Comment: Why do you need it ?, are you looking for a solution to block these bots , what is the need of being peculiar about names there ? . if you elaborate we can help you out to solve your problem

Comment: No, I dont want to block, In my CMS I build a script that follow after the bots and make some report of the pages the bot scanned in my site... so I want to rich the bots names to get better performance in my CMS. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is list of all sort of user agents (BOts spiders and others) [User agents](http://www.user-agents.org/)  , You can use the exact string name to verify